# Pandas : Add value to a cell using loops

Tags: python, pandas

There is a need for me to add values to a cell using loops. I can achieve the result I seek using the script below, however the need is to add values in a cell using loops. Shared below is the code script.

```
import pandas as pd

host = ['R1','R2','R3','R4','R5']
ip = ['192.168.1.10','192.168.1.20','192.168.1.30','192.168.1.40','192.168.1.50']

data = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname' : host,'IP Address' : ip})

# I can create a data frame this way value this way :
data

    Hostname    IP Address
0   R1  192.168.1.10
1   R2  192.168.1.20
2   R3  192.168.1.30
3   R4  192.168.1.40
4   R5  192.168.1.50
```

How to add content of list (host, ip) using a loop :

```
for h,i in zip(host,ip):
    # add script 
    
Seek result as:

    Hostname    IP Address
0   R1  192.168.1.10
1   R2  192.168.1.20
2   R3  192.168.1.30
3   R4  192.168.1.40
4   R5  192.168.1.50
```

Comment: seek result is same as data. can you explain?

Comment: Use loop and create a dataframe. Dataframe should be in the format as listed above.

Comment: @ver_roh Shouldn't my answer be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `append()`

```
import pandas as pd

host = ['R1','R2','R3','R4','R5']
ip = ['192.168.1.10','192.168.1.20','192.168.1.30','192.168.1.40','192.168.1.50']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for h,i in zip(host,ip):
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Hostname': [h], 'IP Address': [i]}), ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Hostname    IP Address
0       R1  192.168.1.10
1       R2  192.168.1.20
2       R3  192.168.1.30
3       R4  192.168.1.40
4       R5  192.168.1.50
```

Comment: Although this depends on which version of Pandas you are currently using as the dataframe append method has been deprecated since version 1.4.0 [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use loc and loop through it to add to cell

```
host = ['R1','R2','R3','R4','R5']
ip = ['192.168.1.10','192.168.1.20','192.168.1.30','192.168.1.40','192.168.1.50']

data = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname' : host,'IP Address' : ip})

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Hostname', 'IP Address'])

for h,i in zip(host,ip):
    df.loc[len(df)] = [h, i]

data = pd.concat([data, df])

data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

print(data)
```

output:

```
  Hostname    IP Address
0       R1  192.168.1.10
1       R2  192.168.1.20
2       R3  192.168.1.30
3       R4  192.168.1.40
4       R5  192.168.1.50
5       R1  192.168.1.10
6       R2  192.168.1.20
7       R3  192.168.1.30
8       R4  192.168.1.40
9       R5  192.168.1.50
```

Comment: There is no point to the Loop and using `.loc`. You could just use `df = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname' : host,'IP Address' : ip})` and then concat with existing DataFrame.